PUT Method in Azure Devops Variable group not working
I am trying to update the variable group using below method
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=7.2-preview.2

But its not working for me in powershell can some one help me to fix this
Script
# Parameters
$organization = "nprod"
$project = "APM"
$pat = "shgksdghiddsfgdertwetrweghdhfgkhsd"  # Your PAT token
$variableGroupName = "Test-Variable-group"
$outputValue = "DaaS"
# Headers for API requests
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
}
# Get the list of variable groups to find the ID
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
$variableGroup = $response.value | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $variableGroupName }
if ($null -eq $variableGroup) {
    Write-Error "Variable group '$variableGroupName' not found."
    exit 1
}
$variableGroupId = $variableGroup.id
# Construct the body for the update
# First, get the existing variables to avoid overwriting the
$existingVariables = @{}
$variableGroup.variables | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Key -ne $null -and $_.Value -ne $null) {
        $existingVariables[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Skipping variable with null key or value."
    }
}
# Add or update the specific variable
$existingVariables["stoppedCjobs"] = @{
    value = $outputValue
}
$body = @{
    id = $variableGroupId
    name = $variableGroupName
    type = "Vsts"
    variables = $existingVariables
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
# Update the variable group
#PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=7.2-preview.2
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$variableGroupId"+"?api-version=7.2-preview.2"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body
if ($response -ne $null) {
    Write-Output "Variable group updated successfully."
} else {
    Write-Error "Failed to update the variable group."
}


And getting error like

WARNING: Skipping variable with null key or value.
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Project information name is not valid for variable group.","typeName":"System.ArgumentException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At line:44 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

want to figure this out issue

To iterate over the variables correctly, you need to use PSObject.Properties.
Also, to update the variables, you must include the variableGroupProjectReferences property within the body of the PUT call.
Refer this:
# Parameters
$organization = "nprod"
$project = "APM"
$pat = "shgksdghiddsfgdertwetrweghdhfgkhsd"  # Your PAT token
$variableGroupName = "Test-Variable-group"
$outputValue = "DaaS"
# Headers for API requests
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
}
# Get the list of variable groups to find the ID
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers
$variableGroup = $response.value | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $variableGroupName }
if ($null -eq $variableGroup) {
    Write-Error "Variable group '$variableGroupName' not found."
    exit 1
}
$variableGroupId = $variableGroup.id
# Construct the body for the update
# First, get the existing variables to avoid overwriting the
$existingVariables = @{}
$variableGroup.variables.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -ne $null -and $_.Value -ne $null) {
        $existingVariables[$_.Name] = $_.Value
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Skipping variable with null key or value."
    }
}
# Add or update the specific variable
$existingVariables["stoppedCjobs"] = @{
    value = $outputValue
}
$body = @{
    id = $variableGroupId
    name = $variableGroupName
    variables = $existingVariables
    variableGroupProjectReferences = @(
        @{
            projectReference = @{
                name = $project
            }
            name = $variableGroup.name
        }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
# Update the variable group
#PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=7.2-preview.2
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$variableGroupId"+"?api-version=7.2-preview.2"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $body
if ($response -ne $null) {
    Write-Output "Variable group updated successfully."
} else {
    Write-Error "Failed to update the variable group."
}


That worked through Local machine , but while i try from ADO pipeline i am not getting GET response , Seems value of $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers is not printing right value , can you help me to fix
| Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Variable group
| 'cjob-nonstart' not found.

@pks, check if you have the variable group cjob-nonstart in your project, and you have specified correct value for the parameters in the script. The script is working in pipeline on my side.

You are welcome. Feel free to let us know if you still have any queries.
